# Group and count the number of occurrences of an ObjectID stored in two separate fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB and I am not sure how to solve in an efficient way this problem.
In my app, a user can choose between one object or another (multiple times, by giving positive/negative ratings). What I want to do is to count how many times an object has been rated positive and negative.
To give you a more precise idea, here is some data sample (I removed some fields to make it simpler) (I need the data in this form because a user is not allowed to rate the same pair of objects twice):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579688a5336f04d208747fe8"),
    "positive" : ObjectId("5796708d58cc25ab040a6cda"),
    "negative" : ObjectId("5796705c58cc25ab040a6cd7")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579688a7336f04d208747fe9"),
    "positive" : ObjectId("5796706358cc25ab040a6cd8"),
    "negative" : ObjectId("5796708058cc25ab040a6cd9")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579688a8336f04d208747fea"),
    "positive" : ObjectId("5796708d58cc25ab040a6cda"),
    "negative" : ObjectId("5796706358cc25ab040a6cd8")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579688a8336f04d208747feb"),
    "positive" : ObjectId("5796708d58cc25ab040a6cda"),
    "negative" : ObjectId("5796706358cc25ab040a6cd8")
}...
```

I need to run a command which returns data in this way:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5796708d58cc25ab040a6cda"),
  "positiveCount": 3,
  "negativeCount": 0
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5796705c58cc25ab040a6cd7"),
  "positiveCount": 0,
  "negativeCount": 1
}, ...
```

So far I am able to count just the number of positive or negative ratings separately using this command:

```
db.getCollection('votes').aggregate([
{$group:{_id:'$positive', count: {$sum:1}}}
]);
```

This works but only to count either positive or negative votes. This is the result I get

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57971bb60711a9a6046dccc7"),
    "count" : 7.0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5796708058cc25ab040a6cd9"),
    "count" : 21.0
}...
```

My solution so far is to run the query twice (one for positive and one for negative ratings) and then merge them in the app level. I am asking you if there is a better and more performant way to achieve this result.
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use a mapReduce function. Here is a possible solution :

```
var map = function() {
    if (this.positive) {
        emit(this.positive, { positiveCount: 1, negativeCount: 0 });
    }
    if (this.negative) {
        emit(this.negative, { positiveCount: 0, negativeCount: 1 });
    }
};

var reduce = function (key, values) {
     var o = { positiveCount: 0, negativeCount: 0 };
     for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
         if (values[i].positiveCount === 1) {
             o.positiveCount++;
         }
         if (values[i].negativeCount === -1) {
             o.negativeCount++;
         }
     }
     return o;
};

db.pairs.mapReduce(map, reduce, { out: "solution" } );
```

Now, you have the total count positive/negative. Query the `solution` collection and you can see results.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've already thought about this solution but it doesn't fit my requirements. I need to run a query because I'll had some filters too, like "get  positive/negative votes for ratings made after a specific date".  To make it more clear: a user cannot vote twice for a specific pair of objects, but he can still vote the same object multiple times (against different objects). I hope it's a bit more clear now

Comment: Not really no. I mean, what solution is close to your needs ? Why it does not fit, what is missing ?

Comment: In my question I posted a partial solution: it is a query which counts how many times a document has been rated positive but I need the number of negative ratings too (for the same document). I also posted the expected result that I need.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. I think a mapReduce function should do the trick. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer really helped me. There was a little issue: when the emit function emits only a single value for a specific Id, then the reduce function will not be called. Therefore I had to add a finalize function to manage this case. I uploaded the final version using mongoose here: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5dyYnCd4)

Comment: Ah, that it is maybe why mongodb recommend to send the send object format on both `map` and `reduce` function. I don't think the `finalize` function is necessary. I updated my answer. Is it better ?